# Select multiple columns in Excel using applescript

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to teach myself AppleScript on something that I actually need AppleScript for.

(I know there must be shortcuts for something that is repeated but I couldn't find a good tutorial on how to do this, so I did it the long way.)

I'm stuck on how to select multiple columns (or rows) at once. I would like to select the populated columns and sort them but I can't because I don't know how to select multiple columns. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

What I would like the script to do is:

- Open an Excel file
- Delete rows 1-32
- Delete columns 4-7
- Delete the new column 7
- Select columns 1-5
- Sort columns 1-5, first by Task, second by Sample
- Delete the rows that include ENDO
- Save file

Here is what I have so far:

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
activate
open (choose file)
end tell

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete row 1
    delete column 4
    delete column 4
    delete column 4
    delete column 4
    delete column 7
    select row 1
    select row 2
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started: [Excel 2004 AppleScript Reference](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/A/7/3A70FB4B-0C6A-43E3-AAB7-AC9166B25632/Excel2004AppleScriptRef.pdf)

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet of active workbook
        set myRows to range "1:27"
        delete myRows
        set myColumn to range "D:G"
        delete myColumn
    end tell
end tell
```